# how can I auto import classes into rule file?

Tags: drools

I can write a rule as below but i don't want to import classes in rule file. Is there a way to "auto" import / register those classes with drools so that I don't need them imported "manually" in rule file. thanks.

```
import entity.Plant 
rule "r1"
    when 
        plant: Plant(name=="ali")
    then
        plant.setType( "boss" );
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. It's just like dealing with a regular *.java file -- you have to have your import statements at the top so that the compiler knows exactly which classes you're using.

Comment: classes that rules will operate on could be registered with the compiler before compiling the rules, so rule file could be cleaner. groovy compiler can do that , i am surprised drools can't.

Comment: I'm surprised you think Drools could. The Java compiler doesn't do that; the fact that the Groovy compiler does isn't ... well I don't see what it has to do with anything. Drools doesn't use the Groovy compiler to do anything.

Comment: :) i know they are apples'n oranges , and drools doesn't use groovy.. i meant , it's a neat trick to pre-include classes in the "script" and drools may add this feature in the future.. https://melix.github.io/blog/2011/05/12/customizing_groovy_compilation_process.html

Comment: Part of the problem is that Drools allows recompilation of rules at runtime, so you'd have to teach the Drools compiler how to compile your _app_ as well. I wouldn't hold my breath. ;)

Comment: If Drools is able to allow recompilation of rules at runtime it could include an auto import file as well. It's code , anything is possible. Auto import is a good feature of Groovy that saves scripts from importing same bunch of classes over and over in every script. Drools is similar to Groovy in terms of "scripting" a host application and it can make use of a useful Groovy paradigm.